# Best practice for controller method returns based on prefix

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, controller

in `web.php` i have two routes one for **admin** and other one for **users** as below

```php
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::get('', [AdminController::class, 'index'])->name('admin');
    Route::resources(['categories' => CategoryController::class);
});

Route::resources(['categories' => CategoryController::class);
```

Then I have `CategoryController.php` that gets data from the database and returns a view:

```php
public static function index()
{
    $categories = Category::paginate(5);

    return response()->view('categories.categories', ['categories' => $categories]);
}
```

I want to change the view template based on if it goes `/admin/categories` or it goes `/categories`.

I have a solution but I want to know the best practice for that for all functions in `CategoryController`

`index`, `create`, `store`, `show`, `edit`, `update`, and `destroy`.

Comment: what is the solution you have? ...

Comment: The way of handling this is to have fixed controllers/methods for specific routes. You should never use the same controller/method for multiple routes...